Converting 2D lines in a plane into 3D lines in a space
I've been trying to club some theory from 3D geometry and 2D geometry to make it easier to remember. Is there an easy way to convert a 2D line (say $x+2y=3$) into the standard 3D form of $$\frac{x-x_1}a=\frac{y-y_1}b=\frac{z-z_1}c=r$$ ?
(Obviously, I don't expect there to be a $z$ component).

A 3-dimensional version of a line is given by the intersection of any two non-congruent intersecting planes. To be more specific, any line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be represented by the following system of equations: $$\begin{cases}
A_1x+B_1y+C_1z+D_1=0\
A_2x+B_2y+C_2z+D_2=0\
\end{cases},$$ where $(A_1,B_1,C_1),(A_2,B_2,C_2)\neq (0,0,0)$.

For the $z$ component to vanish for all possible values of the parameter $r$, $\forall r\mid rc+z_1=0$, implying $c=0$, which makes $\frac{z-z_1}{c}$ undefined.

Your "standard" 3D form is not completely general. It describes only lines that are not parallel to any of the coordinate planes. Hence the answer to your question is "no", since the "2D" line is parallel to a coordinate plane.

The "standard" form is not a single equation. It is actually two equations written together (depending on how you count them). One way to handle this situation is to stop writing them together and adjust the second equation to handle the $0$ direction: $$\frac{x-x_1}a=\frac{y-y_1}b\z - z_1 = 0$$ Or, since you've uselessly added the arbitrary parameter $r$ to the standard form, you could actually make some use of it and write the equation in parametric form: $$(x,y,z) = (x_1 + ar, y_1 + br, z_1 + cr), r\in \Bbb R$$
